# How to get the full track mp3 url?

Tags: deezer

Through the track api I got preview field,it can provide a 30 second address.but I want get a full track mp3 url, excuse how to get the full track mp3 url by deezer API when I have a Premium+ users token.Thinks.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to play a full track is by using our SDKs available here: http://developers.deezer.com

There is no possibility to retrieve the MP3 URL.

Comment: Could you please clarify, there is no way to retrieve MP3 urls meaning I can only play songs with your C/C++/Java/iOS api? The reason I'm asking this is because I wanted to write a console player for Deezer in Golang, so that deems it impossible, right?

Comment: also, a follow-up question, will there be a Golang API?

Comment: It is not planned to have a Golang API, I'm sorry. The only way to play full tracks is to use our SDK.

Comment: @Fred_Dzr Hi, is there any chance that JS SDK player can work without Flash?